# WPF - Center Label in Grid Cell when Font Size Changed

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, label, center

Separate a Grid into multiple sections like this:

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Now create a label which centers the content in the cell.

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Hello World"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Label>
```

Observe that it seems to be centered.

Now, change the font of the label to anything larger than 12. The larger the better, for example 24.

```
<Label FontSize="24" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Hello World"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Label>
```

See that the text is no longer centered.

How can I center the text into the cell keeping into account the size of the text? I don't want to specifically define a Margin for each one which does work, but it requires trial and error and is not very efficient.

I'm looking for ideally a pure WPF/XAML solution, built in or custom. Though it seems to me this functionality might require a converter and a custom style targeting a label which is unfortunate as it seems like a fair amount of effort for something so simple.

Is there an easy solution to this?

Comment: I am afraid your problem is not reproducable: using the same XAML, the text remains centered (in the top left cell) no matter the fontsize... Maybe there is something else in the XAML you did not list here. Try to include a complete XAML listing that reproduces the problem... Note 'Now create a label which centers the content in the grid.' Your XAML will never center the label in the grid, it will center it in the top left cell.

Comment: You're right actually, it seems in the example I provided the text is centered. I see my problem is actually that, the height of the row is not large enough to be centered properly, if that makes sense.

If you were to take that same example, and set the RowDefinition Height to a smaller amount such that the font is just visible. You will see that the text is no longer centered, but is in fact lower down in the cell. Try this value <RowDefinition Height="36" />. Clearly in this case, the Label can be centered in the grid cell vertically but it is not.

And I mean't cell, will edit that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you describe is caused by the `Padding` within the Label (which is not zero by default).

try:

```
<Label Padding="0" FontSize="30"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Hello World"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
```

Note: if the height for the row is too small to accomodate the fontsize, the visible part of the text will be the upper part, not the center part. 
I guess it would be quiet useless for the renderer to try to center the text in that case.

Comment: Based on my example I believe this is correct and what I was looking for. Thank you, I will mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question clearly.But I think this is the line of code you want.I just added a col span property to the code.

```
< Label FontSize="24" Grid.Row="0" Background="AliceBlue" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Hello World"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">< /Label>
```